# How to fetch form values for Simple hierarchical select?

Tags: forms, 9

I have referenced a field with taxonomy by using simple hierarchical module and now I have to fetch the options programmatically to perform some actions on them.
I tried to fetch it like the below it didn't work out.

```
$form['field_delivery_methods']['widget']['#options'];
```

This worked on shs [8.x-1.0-alpha5](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs/releases/8.x-1.0-alpha5) but after upgrading to [shs 2.0.0-rc3](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs/releases/2.0.0-rc3) its not working. Does anyone help me in understanding the latest structure on how to fetch the options?

Answer (score -3):

You can use `field_info_field()` or can `list_allowed_values()`.

```
$field = field_info_field('field_name');
$allowed_values = list_allowed_values($field);
```

Comment: This is a Drupal 9 question. These functions have been deprecated and removed for a long time.